# Error with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf

I write a code for a simple diagram using tikz-cd and does not compile. I don't know why, I have installed texlive-full in lubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
\begin{tikzcd}

& C^\prime \arrow[dr, "g"]  & \\

C \arrow[ur, "f"]\arrow[rr, "g\circ f"] &   & C^{\prime\prime}

\end{tikzcd}
```

The error given is "Package tikz-cd Error: Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters u, d, l, r.".

If I write only one r instead of two, the same error message appear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only get errors because you can't put blank lines inside the `tikzcd` environment.

If you remove them, it compiles fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& C^\prime \arrow[dr, "g"]  & \\
C \arrow[ur, "f"]\arrow[rr, "g\circ f"] &   & C^{\prime\prime}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have an old `tikz-cd` you can try with the old syntax of `\arrow`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& C^\prime \arrow{dr}{g}  & \\
C \arrow{ur}{f}\arrow{rr}{g\circ f} &   & C^{\prime\prime}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

If it still fails, try adding blank atoms `{}` at empty positions (thanks to daleif for the suggestion), so either

```
\begin{tikzcd}
{} & C^\prime \arrow[dr, "g"]  & {}\\
C \arrow[ur, "f"]\arrow[rr, "g\circ f"] & {} & C^{\prime\prime}
\end{tikzcd}
```

or (with old syntax)

```
\begin{tikzcd}
{} & C^\prime \arrow{dr}{g}  & {}\\
C \arrow{ur}{f}\arrow{rr}{g\circ f} & {} & C^{\prime\prime}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Thanks, but.. if I copy and paste your code I obtain the following error message:

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.74 &C^
\prime \arrow[dr, "g"] & \\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Comment: I already tried with that, but doesn't work either

Comment: @User You should update your TeX distribution...

Comment: Can you explain me how I should do that? I have the 2. 1 version of pgf. I had just installed this (14.04 LTS) distribution of lubuntu and installed texlive-full.. 
What should I do now?

Comment: I think I realised why that code doesn't compile. I must write a white space with "\ " instead of nothing at all. I mean, the correct code will be:


`\begin{tikzcd}
\ &C^\prime \arrow{rd}{g}  &\\
C \arrow{ur}{f}\arrow{rr}{g\circ f} &   & C^{\prime\prime}
\end{tikzcd}`


I'm not sure if I must put this as a comment or as an answer. Thank you for your time (:

Comment: This shouldn't be needed...

Comment: Yes, I know it shouldn't be. But that code compiles and the others don't. I don't know why it is needed only in the first place. Maybe if there isn't a character, doesn't take into account the first "&".

Comment: @User See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/27635).

Comment: I'd just write `{}` in the blank cells. I've seen tikzcd fail because it could not detect anything in a cell. Adding a blank atom usually does the trick